# ¿Como podría sacar el Promedio Final con mis campos Tipo y Nota de mi tabla Evaluación?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Estoy haciendo un `Stored Procedure` que me pide como parámetros a `Id_Estudiante` e `Id_Curso`
y me retorne el Promedio Final ponderando los Tipos de Evaluaciones. Lo he intentado unas 3 veces y no me bota nada.

Debo tener en cuenta:

```
20%(PC1) + 20%(PC2) + 30%(TF) + 30%(EB)
```

[image: Estructura de la base]

Mi Stored Procedure es el siguiente:

```
Create Proc Nota_Final (
    @id_estudiante Char(4),
    @id_curso Char(3))
As
    Select c.Id_Curso , e.Id_Estudiante , Nota_Final = (Select Nota * 0.20 from Evaluacion where Tipo ='PC1') + (Select Nota * 0.20 from Evaluacion where Tipo ='PC2') 
    + (Select Nota * 0.30 from Evaluacion where Tipo ='TF') + (Select Nota * 0.30 from Evaluacion where Tipo ='EB')
    from Evaluacion e inner join Curso c
    on e.Id_Curso = c.Id_Curso 
    inner join Estudiante_Curso ec
    on e.Id_Estudiante = ec.Id_Estudiante 
    where e.Id_Estudiante = @id_estudiante and c.Id_Curso = @id_curso
    group by c.Id_Curso , e.Id_Estudiante , Nota_Final
go
    exec Nota_Final 'A001','A02'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no necesitas ningún dato del estudiante ni del curso, entonces no hay necesidad de hacer joins con esas tablas. Basta con usar únicamente la tabla `Evaluacion`:

```
SELECT  id_Cursom
        id_EStudiante,
        Nota_Final = 0.2*PC1 + 0.2*PC2 + 0.3*TF + 0.3*EB
FROM (  SELECT  id_Curso,
                id_Estudiante,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'PC1' THEN Nota END) PC1,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'PC2' THEN Nota END) PC2,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'TF' THEN Nota END) TF,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'EB' THEN Nota END) EB
        FROM Evaluacion
        WHERE Id_Estudiante = @id_estudiante 
        AND Id_Curso = @id_curso
        GROUP BY id_Curso,
                 id_Estudiante) T
;
```

En caso de que necesites calcular un promedio aún cuando no haya una nota, entonces puedes usar la nota mínima:

```
SELECT  id_Cursom
        id_EStudiante,
        Nota_Final = 0.2*ISNULL(PC1,5) + 0.2*ISNULL(PC2,5) + 0.3*ISNULL(TF,5) + 0.3*ISNULL(EB,5)
FROM (  SELECT  id_Curso,
                id_Estudiante,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'PC1' THEN Nota END) PC1,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'PC2' THEN Nota END) PC2,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'TF' THEN Nota END) TF,
                MIN(CASE WHEN Tipo = 'EB' THEN Nota END) EB
        FROM Evaluacion
        WHERE Id_Estudiante = @id_estudiante 
        AND Id_Curso = @id_curso
        GROUP BY id_Curso,
                 id_Estudiante) T
;
```

Comment: Holaaa amigo, tu ayuda esta genial, pero sabes solo me bota el promedio final cuando están los 4 Tipos de Evaluación, pero digamos que el alumno  solo tenga 3 o 2 Tipos de Evaluación e igual quiero su promedio.  En ese caso seria conveniente una condición o bueno que me aconsejas por favor ??, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @GroverCristobal Pero en caso que no esté una nota, qué valor debe tomar para calcular el promedio?. Cuál es la nota mínima?

Comment: Ah claro disculpa, la nota mínima es 5

Comment: @GroverCristobal Ok, actualizada la respuesta

Comment: gracias amigo, lo que pasa es que yo estaba acostumbrado a sacar Promedios Aritméticos, pero con este ejercicio me hice un gran problema, ya que es Promedio Ponderado y bueno ya lo comprendí!!

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez se debería seleccionar por curso y estudiante en las subconsultas:

```
Nota_Final = (Select Nota * 0.20 from Evaluacion WHERE Tipo ='PC1' AND Id_Estudiante=@id_estudiante AND Id_Curso=@id_curso) 
  + (Select Nota * 0.20 from Evaluacion WHERE Tipo ='PC2' AND Id_Estudiante=@id_estudiante AND Id_Curso=@id_curso) 
  + (Select Nota * 0.30 from Evaluacion WHERE Tipo ='TF' AND Id_Estudiante=@id_estudiante AND Id_Curso=@id_curso)  
  + (Select Nota * 0.30 from Evaluacion WHERE Tipo ='EB' AND Id_Estudiante=@id_estudiante AND Id_Curso=@id_curso)
```

Comment: gracias por su aporte mi buen amigo!